# Jquery Error Notification

Tags: jquery

```
<label class="num">X</label>
<label class="date">X</label>
```

I am using jquery for clientside validation , i use html labels for notifying errors.
For showing errors in numeric fields i use label with class num.
For showing errors in the date fields i use label with class date.
The text of both the label is 'X' with color red.So not so self explanatory.
I was wondering if i can use tooltips on hover of these labels to display more explanatory errors , any idea as to how i can use tooltips for my purpose.
Is it possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use below plugin for this. It supports both validation and tooltips

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Here the samples

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/